# Multi-model form problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

(I'm just learning rails so....)
I have a photo model and a gallery model, habtm associations and a join table. I'm making a photo gallery. The gallery page has a title field and description field. User creates gallery title, then goes to the photo page and checkboxes each image they want in that gallery.

I get the error "undefined method `to_i' for ["1", {"title"=>"1"}]:Array" when trying to save/update a photo with a gallery title(with the checkbox)

```
<% form_for @photo, :html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>


<% for gallery in @photo.galleries %>
<% fields_for "painting[gallery_attributes][]", gallery do |g| %>
<div>
  <%= g.check_box :title %>
  <%= gallery.title %>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<p><%= submit_tag 'Update' %></p>
<% end %>
```

How much of this is horribly wrong?
Can someone point me in the right direction?, I can't find any tutorials relating to this for 2.3 and above.

Comment: We would need to take a look at your model and controller, because it looks like the error isn't related to how you have your view setup. Are you using accepts_nested_attributes_for? in your Photo model? Also check the type of your title attribute in your gallery model and make sure it is set properly, in case you have an int when you want a string or vice versa..

Answer (score 2):

For this complicated task of having multiple models updated with a single form, i would recommend the three part series in railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2

http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-3

Though please if another forum member knows of a better/more up-to-date tutorial let me know, i did this back in the day and it was a pain.

Comment: Ryan did an update on these railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was a good example of nested forms http://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples/